# How do I remove or revise a rule that I created?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

How do I revise or remove a rule in Outlook that I created?

Comment: Which version of outlook are you using?  You need to add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Outlook 2003, click the "Tools" menu and then "Rules and Alerts". There will be options for you to change or removed rules you have created.

If you are using Outlook 2010, there is a Rules icon on the Home ribbon. Clicking it will give you an option for "Manage Rules and Alerts".